# How to Copy some number of files from one directory to another with cp command?

Tags: list, command, limit, cp

I have 100 files in one folder. Their names are 1 to 100.

I want to copy files 1 to 50 into another folder named `a`. Something like this, which is not nice work:

```
cp 1 2 ... 50 ./a
```

Comment: So make a bash script with a for loop iterating from 1 to 100. For each iteration you execute a single copy command. You specify the target folder inside the copy command based on a comparison of the current iteration index (the number) against 50. Post your script if you run into problems and we will be happy to assist.

Comment: You litereally show no effort on your side ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cp `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | head -50` a

cp `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | tail -50` b